# Не могу понять почему не создается сессия Hibernate в Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть Бин, в котором объявляется сервлет и конфиг для БД

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru, ru.instance" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/:3306/OrganizerDB?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="sasha"/>
    <property name="password" value="sasha"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.instance"/>
    <property name="annotatedPackages" value="ru.instance"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Так же есть класс

```
@Component
public class UsersClass{
 private static final Logger _log = LogManager.getLogger(UsersClass.class.getName());

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public void getAll() {
        System.out.println("Sesion: " + this.sessionFactory);
 }
}
```

Но сессия все равно не создается. Можете помочь в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: что значит сессия не создается? здесь вы просто просите спринг передать sessionFactory в поле.

Comment: @etki если я правильно понял, то должно произойти следующее : при объявлении аннотации '@Aurowired' в переменной sessionFactory должна инициализироваться сессия. И в выводе я получу не null. Но вот сейчас именно этого не происходит .

Comment: А как UsersClass получаете?

Comment: @Etki `UsersClass usersClass = new UsersClass();
        usersClass.getAll();`
Вызываю таким образом метод

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что, на самом деле, никакой магии в спринге нет, все, что в нем делается - это довольно простые вызовы кода.

`@Autowired` действительно предназначен для автоматической установки значений, но, повторюсь, никакой магии не существует, и чтобы это произошло, спрингу нужно получить (иногда - создать) объект и обработать его в своем DI-контейнере. В вашем случае этого не происходит, потому что спринг здесь никак не участвует:

```
// магии не произошло, потому что @Autowired действует не на уровне языка, 
// а на уровне Spring
UsersClass usersClass = new UsersClass();
// JVM создала новый объект с неициниализированным полем, оттуда вы и получаете null
```

Для того, чтобы получить нормальный экземпляр с заполненным полем, вам нужно воспользоваться контейнером Spring. В общем случае это происходит так же через `@Autowired`:

```
@Controller
public class CustomController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersClass userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public List<User> getAll() {
        userRepository.getAll();
        return null;
    }
}
```

В этом случае Spring

1. Найдет аннотацию @Component на вашем UsersClass (NB: при этом вы так или иначе должны заранее сказать спрингу, что нужно просканировать один из родительских пакетов, см. `@ComponentScan`)
2. Найдет все @Autowired-аннотации в нем
3. Создаст новый экземпляр UsersClass (есть некоторые тонкости с `@Autowired`-конструкторами, но пока не будем об этом)
4. Найдет в контейнере созданную `SessionFactory` (или создаст ее)
5. С помощью рефлексии проинициализирует поле
6. Добавит экземпляр `UsersClass` в контейнер
7. После чего аналогичным образом проинициализирует контроллер

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!) Во-первых получилось выполнить то, что хотел, а во-вторых буду читать про то, что вы написали тут)